# How to enable USB debugging on Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300 when touch not working

Tags: android, usb, galaxy

I bricked my phone so now touch doesn't work on my Galaxy S3. I want to use a windows tool Android Screencast so that I could still use my phone from my PC before I get the replacement part.

To be able to use it I have to enable USB debugging on my phone so that ADB will recognize my device. But as I said I cannot use touch screen. So is there another way to enable USB debugging? Or is there a ROM that has this function pre enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect an external mouse or keyboard and navigate the phone that way.

Bluetooth or USB will work.